# Fetch all epics using ruby-jira gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jira, jira-rest-api

I've been playing with Jira API via the `jira-ruby` gem. I have a task where I would like to list all the epics that belong to a user's account. My current solution is to get all the issues and return items with `issuetype` name set to `Epic`.

```
def list_epics
  @epics = []
  begin
    all_issues = @jira_client.Issue.all
    all_issues.each do |issue|
      @epics << issue if issue.fields.issuetype.name == 'Epic'
    end
  rescue JIRA::HTTPError
    puts "Jira API error"
  end
  @epics
end
```

`@jira_client` represents an authenticated user account.

Even though the above code works, but I assume it's a naive and inefficient solution. Besides I couldn't find much information from the documentation page of `jira-ruby` project. So any help is appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, do you mean the `jira-ruby` gem, not `ruby-jira`? I can't find a gem called `ruby-jira`.

Comment: What is your question? You've posted code that looks like a potentially valid solution, with no mention of any result/error message.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. This can be achieved by using `jql` as shown below.

```
epics  = @jira_client.Issue.jql('issuetype=Epic')
```

Hope it'll help someone else.